# Creating Runtime content for ArcGIS 10.0

Tags: android, arcgis, arcgis-server

I was trying to run "hello world" of ArcGIS sdk samples, but my program was showing a blank output b/c. It couldn't connect to ArcGIS online server. So I goggled a way to create and stored my map locally and I found that it was possible by creating Runtime content, but this feature is only available for Arcmap 10.2 and above, but I have arcmap 10.0, so can anybody give me a clue on how to use Arcmap 10.0 or any other technique. Please I need this very much. 
I got my resource at 
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00660000045q000000

Answer (score 0):

Creating Runtime content is a new feature in ArcGIS 10.2. You'll need to upgrade to ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.

Comment: ethe problem is i have the cracked arcgis and i dont think i can update it.if u can can u please tell me where to find the cracked 10.2.thanks

Comment: and @Gary,can i contact u through mail,please.atleast u can help me on what tools to use for my project.i am a graduating student in need of help,please,and i only need help on how to start

Comment: I don't know and wouldn't say where to get cracked software, but you can get a legal copy of ArcGIS Desktop for free through the [education use program](http://www.esri.com/industries/apps/education/offers/promo/index.cfm) or cheap through the [home use program](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-home). If you're a student, you might check with your university's geography department to see if they already have ArcGIS.